# Cannot get preview to work on anything below API 23

Tags: android, android-studio

I cannot get any preview below API 23 to show in Android Studio. Does anyone have a solution to this? This problem has been happening since updated to 1.4 and I think it has something to do with the new activity_main.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the new components like CoordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton, AppBarLayout, etc. make this happen.

Using the support library (e.g.android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton) will let you use them in previous API versions of your applications.

Unfortunately using support library does not solve the preview issue, only the compilation and usage issue. I guess that until this is fixed, we have to use the API 23 preview.

Comment: I've been having problems creating custom themes after updating to 1.4. Very annoying

Answer (score 0):

In order to see previews for versions other than API 23 in Android Studio, you need to have the APIs that you want previews for installed. So, if I want to see a preview for APIs 14, 16, 19 and 21, I would need to installed then via the SDK manager.